# Convexity of quantum Fisher information

Tags: convex-analysis, quantum-computation

Let $R$ be any quantum state and $X$ any observable, then we define
$$F(R, X) = 4 \operatorname{Tr} \left( L^2 R \right)$$ as the quantum Fisher information, where $L$ is the logarithmic derivative determined by
$$i(RX - XR) = \frac{LR + RL}{2}$$

I know that the Fisher information is a convex function but I can not prove this. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the quantum Fisher information is defined as
$$
F(\rho(x)) = \operatorname{Tr}(\rho(x) L^2),
$$
where $x\in \mathbb R$ is an unknown parameter and where $L$ is the symmetric logarithmic derivative, which is implicitly defined as
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \rho = \frac12(\rho L + L \rho).
$$
For your problem, $L$ is not really of concern.  That the Fisher information is convex in $\rho$ is a simple consequence of the linearity of the trace.  And all linear functions are convex.